# .ipa File in iPad is Blank but working in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have Created an ipa file for the Client. The deployment Target has been set to `iPhone/iPad` I have two storyboard in my Project i.e iPad Story board and  iPhone Story board.

The iPhone Storyboard has all the layouts and screens but the ipad storyboard empty without any screens. My project is only for `iPhone`. But my client has an iPad to test the ipa file. My problem is CLient says when he installs the App he can see a white screen. What Target setting I should change to run the iPhone Application in iPad ?

Comment: check whether the iphone and ipad storyboard name is correct that you are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create ipa for iphone.
- First os all change settings in General>Devices>iPhone and then create ipa
- When ipa is created for iPhone its run on both iPhone and iPad device, but in iPad shows as iPhone layout.

Comment: should i need to change Built setting-> Targetted Device Family to iphone only ???

Comment: its automatically change as iPhone when u change device iphone.

Answer (score 2):

Select your Project target, in `Gernal` tab goto `Deployment info` there select `iPad` and in `main interface` select your `iphone storyboard` (Refer screenshot) [image]

Also make sure you `set` same ViewController for iPad as you did for iPhone, for doing that:-

Go to your iPad story board-->select View controller-->Identity Inspector and set the `Class` under `Custom Class` heading as the name of your `iphone ViewController`.

[image]